# How to change dropdown items in combobox with change of text?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am working on POS using EPF C#. To add saleline items I want to use combobox and want to change selection for its dropdown with the change of text in combobox to search? How can I change combox list items with Textchanged property or any other way? And Can I also use datagrid columns or datagrid for this purpose?

Comment: If I am reading the question correctly, couldn't you subscribe to the textinput or keydown event of the combobox? Then all you have to do is write your logic in the event delegate?

Comment: Sorry! that's my fault. I want user to search for product to add into saleline item by writting its name into text box and it will be shown in a DATAGRID as most pos software do But I also want to give him suggestions as he writes name for product like in android to search contact you write one letter and relevent names are shown in list. So, Can Datagrid provide it or Combobox will be the best choice as It has a dropdown list? So, please explain how I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments it appears you want a textbox that is able to filter a list of items. My suggestion would be to subscribe to the textboxes "textchanged" event.

```
textbox.TextChanged += Textbox_TextChanged;
```

Then do the filtering in the method that you used to subscribe to the event with

```
private void Textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do list sorting here ex.)
    List<string> FilteredResults = SomeList<string>.where(i => i.Contains(textbox.text)).ToList();
}
```

This will get you a filtered list of items (strings in this case) that you can then display in the ComboBox.

Note: The MVVM design pattern makes this extremely simple and clean to pull off.

Comment: No problem glad I could help!